# firestore async await foreach vs for

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am using firestore for a while now, I want to implement a call to get data from a subcollection.

I had to create a asynchronous call and foreach() method did not await the call and continued, but it worked with the for() method. Can someone please explain to me why for() waits and foreach() doesn't?

**Foreach()** - doesn't work

```js
export const FirebaseSearchUsers = async (search: string) => {
  const end = search.replace(/.$/, c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1));
  let users: UserDocument[] = [];

  await firestore()
    .collection(FirebaseConstraints.UserCollection)
    .where('username', '>=', search)
    .where('username', '<', end)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(async x => {
      x.forEach(async y => {
        let userDocument: UserDocument = y.data() as UserDocument;
        userDocument.houseInvites = [];

        await y.ref
          .collection(FirebaseConstraints.HouseInvitesCollection)
          .get()
          .then(x => x.forEach(x => userDocument.houseInvites.push(x.data() as HouseInviteDocument)));
        users.push(userDocument);
      });
    });
  return users;
};
```

**For()** -works

```js
export const FirebaseSearchUsers = async (search: string) => {
  const end = search.replace(/.$/, c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1));
  let users: UserDocument[] = [];

    await firestore()
    .collection(FirebaseConstraints.UserCollection)
    .where('username', '>=', search)
    .where('username', '<', end)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(async x => {
      for (let y of x.docs) {
        let userDocument: UserDocument = y.data() as UserDocument;
        userDocument.houseInvites = [];
        await y.ref
          .collection(FirebaseConstraints.HouseInvitesCollection)
          .get()
          .then(x => x.forEach(x => userDocument.houseInvites.push(x.data() as HouseInviteDocument)));
        users.push(userDocument);
      }
    });
  return users;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreach expect synchronous callback ;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill

(2nd yellow memo)

Your for version is good but it's blocking. (you can parallelize your seconds requests to get your results faster)

**EDIT**

To parallelize, maybe this should work ;)

```
export const FirebaseSearchUsers = async (search: string) => {
  const end = search.replace(/.$/, c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1));

  // wrap this in try catch to handle errors ;)

    const usersQuerySnapshot = await firestore()
    .collection(FirebaseConstraints.UserCollection)
    .where('username', '>=', search)
    .where('username', '<', end)
    .limit(10)
    .get();

    const futureUsers = usersQuerySnapshot.docs.map(async userSnapshot => {
      const userDocument: UserDocument = userSnapshot.data() as UserDocument;

      const houseInvitesSnapshots = await userSnapshot.ref
      .collection(FirebaseConstraints.HouseInvitesCollection)
      .get();

      const houseInvites = houseInvitesSnapshots.docs.map(snapshot => snapshot.data() as HouseInviteDocument);

      // or you can use the builtin method forEach of houseInvitesSnapshots and declare a "let" houseInvites array
      // let houseInvites = [];
      // houseInvitesSnapshots.forEach(snapshot => houseInvites.push(snapshot.data() as HouseInviteDocument));
      // these 2 forms should works same (I did not test ;)

      // Then, return a copy of your user document and fill its houseInvites property
      return { ...userDocument, houseInvites};
    })

    const users = await Promise.all(futureUsers);

    return users;
};
```

Comment: That expalins a lot (:  What did you had in mind for the parallelize part? e.g Promise.all?

Comment: Yes, parallelize is breaking your async call in multiple async call and waiting for all to complete. Instead of waiting one by one in the for loop, all async calls fire and with Promise.all(allMyAsyncCallsArray) you get an array with the result. Hard to demonstrate in this comment ^^

Comment: I edit my answer. I can't test that is working but I hope you get the idea. Happy coding !

Comment: Tried the code, it works perfect! Thank you so much for explaining and helping me. You're the MVP, cheers.